# Symfony 2.8 - scssphp requires to clear cache on each change

Tags: php, symfony, filter, sass, assetic

I am currently using leafo/scssphp and it is compiling scss files as expected, but one problem I have is that I have to delete cache every time I make changes to files. I do not get any errors although.

When I was using lessphp my files where compiled automatically once I change them and no cache clearing was necessary. This is what exactly I want when using scssphp too.

Here is my configuration for scssphp filter:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        cssrewrite:     ~
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You didn't describe the problem. Why do you *have to*? What happens if you don't?

Comment: I mention it clearly with example of lessphp that I didn't need to clear cache for less to compile after each change. With sass I need to clear the cache so changess of sass would work.

Comment: You mentioned clearly the workaround that works for you, not how the issue looks like. Describe what it means to "not work". Do you get any errors/warnings etc.?

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `php bin/console assetic:watch` in a separate process